# How to use SAML authentication in angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, angular8

I want to implement `SAML` based authentication in Angular 8 as I have seen implementation in C#

https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

in which first it redirects to the Identity provider URL and get `SAML response ("assertion")`. how can I receive and validate the `SAML response ("assertion")` that I received via POST from the identity `provider(Okta)` I want to do this whole work in Angular 8 so help me in this.

Comment: POST data is data that is handled by server side

Comment: @Ashutosh Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @Mayur No, not yet maybe this cannot be handled on angular. I didn't find any package or any way that can handle that SAML response as in C# there is a Nuget package "AspNetSaml" which does that whole work.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari did you manage to integrate it into Angular by now?

Answer (score 0):

*I assume, you are aware of implementing SAML with server side application.*

I don't think so angular application would be treated as SP (Service Provider) in implementing SAML because angular APP is totally client side application. You have to create SP using any server side language (ASP.Net or any other). There you can send request and get response from IdP (Identity Provider).

After getting SAML assertion and validating it at SP, you can store it in database (SQL or any other). Then you can redirect to angular app with SQL table row id. In angular application, using this row id, you can fetch SAML assertion in the form of JWT.

Angular APP link : https://myangularapp.com/auth

Service Provider link : https://dotnetapp.com/sendSAMLRequest

Identity Provider link : https://identityprovider.com/

Above link are just for understanding and they are not working.

The flow is as below.
[image: SAML in Angular APP]
Angular App -> Service Provider -> Identity Provider

Step 1 : From angular app, redirect to SP with some GUID to maintain track of request.

Redirect to => https://dotnetapp.com/request?id=guidabcd42564

Step 2 : From SP, SAML request with above GUID is sent to IdP.

Step 3 : IdP evaluate the SAML request and send SAML response to SP.

Step 4 : At SP, SAML response is validated and stored in SQL. Then redirect to angular app as https://myangularapp.com/getSAMLResponse?id=123

After this, in angular app, you can get the SAML response from database using row id (in this case it is 123) and store it in local storage.